# I am not being able to use my ES6 syntax in node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I've updated node to the latest version.
Here's a piece of code

```
const fs = require('fs');

const textIn = fs.readFileSync('./txt/input.txt','utf-8'); 
console.log(textIn);

const textOut = 'This is what we know: ${textIn}.\nCreated on ${Date.now()}';
fs.writeFileSync('./txt/output.txt', textOut);
console.log('File Written!');
```

The problem is I could generate an output file while ${textIn} is taken as a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), so you need backticks instead of double or single quotes:

```
const textOut = `This is what we know: ${textIn}.\nCreated on ${Date.now()}`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the string in backticks, not in single quotes to be able to use the value of the variable as a string:

```
const textOut = `This is what we know: ${textIn}.\nCreated on ${Date.now()}`;
```